# batched tensor slice, slice B x N x M with B x 1

Tags: numpy, pytorch, slice, tensor, numpy-slicing

I have an B x M x N tensor, X, and I have and B x 1 tensor, Y, which corresponds to the index of tensor X at dimension=1 that I want to keep.  What is the shorthand for this slice so that I can avoid a loop?

Essentially I want to do this:

```
Z = torch.zeros(B,N)

for i in range(B):
    Z[i] = X[i][Y[i]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by [@Hammad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13250589/hammad) is short and perfect for the job. Here's an alternative solution if you're interested in using some less known Pytorch built-ins. We will use [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) (similarly you can achieve this with [`numpy.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)).

The idea behind `torch.gather` is to construct a new tensor-based on two identically shaped tensors containing the indices (here ~ `Y`) and the values (here ~ `X`).

The operation performed is `Z[i][j][k] = X[i][Y[i][j][k]][k]`.

Since `X`'s shape is `(B, M, N)` and `Y` shape is `(B, 1)` we are looking to fill in the blanks inside `Y` such that `Y`'s shape becomes `(B, 1, N)`.

This can be achieved with some axis manipulation:

```
>>> Y.expand(-1, N)[:, None] # expand to dim=1 to N and unsqueeze dim=1
```

The actual call to `torch.gather` will be:

```
>>> X.gather(dim=1, index=Y.expand(-1, N)[:, None])
```

Which you can reshape to `(B, N)` by adding in `[:, 0]`.

---

This function can be very effective in tricky scenarios...

Comment: thank you! while the previous solution worked, it was not batch-size agnostic.  but this one is!

Comment: I'm glad I *did* post the answer then, even though another one had already been accepted!

Comment: @Ivan can you state the equivalent for numpy (expand)?

Comment: The equivalent to `torch.expand` in Numpy seems to be [`np.broadcaast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html#numpy.broadcast_to)

Comment: @Ivan thanks, but it seems to not work with negative values.

Comment: @Codevan You need to replace the `-1`s with `1`s

Answer (score 3):

the following code is similar to the code in the loop. the difference is that instead of sequentially indexing the array `Z`,`X` and `Y` we are indexing them in parallel using the array `i`

```py
B, M, N = 13, 7, 19

X = np.random.randint(100, size= [B,M,N])
Y = np.random.randint(M  , size= [B,1])
Z = np.random.randint(100, size= [B,N])

i = np.arange(B)
Y = Y.ravel()    # reducing array to rank-1, for easy indexing

Z[i] = X[i,Y[i],:]
```

this code can be further simplified as

```py
>> Z[i] = X[i,Y[i],:]
>> Z[i] = X[i,Y[i]]
>> Z[i] = X[i,Y]
>> Z    = X[i,Y]
```

pytorch equivalent code

```py
B, M, N = 5, 7, 3

X = torch.randint(100, size= [B,M,N])
Y = torch.randint(M  , size= [B,1])
Z = torch.randint(100, size= [B,N])

i = torch.arange(B)
Y = Y.ravel()

Z = X[i,Y]
```

Comment: they say `Y` is of shape `(B, 1)` so you might want to change to `Y.view(-1)` or something similar in the very last expression.